# PHP, Regex - How to escape \n with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I want to replace `\n` with `\\n`, and `\a` with `\\a` and so on...

So this is my regex:

Pattern:

```
([\\])
```

Should be replaced with:

```
$1$1
```

So if the input string is `\n`, it will be replace with `\n`.
(I have tested it at http://www.regexe.com/ and it worked)

Then I had this PHP code:

```
preg_replace('/([\\])/', '$1$1', "\n a");
```

and thought it would output \n a, but instead I got this error:

```
Warning:  preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 5
```

So I have escaped the `[`.

Now my code is

```
  preg_replace('/(\[\\])/','$1$1',"\n a");
```

But.... this doesn't works as I want, because now it is not replacing `\n` with `\\n`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[\\]` is a wrong escaping, you need 4 backslashes to represent one literal ``\``. I'd just suggest using a regular `str_replace` with arrays for search and replace with mapped whitespace and their literal representations.

Comment: You also need to change `"\n a"` to `'\n a'`. Escape sequences are interpreted inside double quotes so `\n` is a newline, not a backslash followed by `n`.

Comment: Have you got any testing framework for this? Do you just target [these PHP escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)?

Comment: As Barmar answered, `preg_replace` is not needed. Further why use a capture group? [`preg_replace('/\\\/', '\\\\\\', '\n a');`](https://eval.in/522094).

Comment: Unless you give more context, there is no real solution. `How to escape \n` - by just saying _`escape`_ you've put it into the realm of string parsing, which is a lot more complicated than you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `preg_replace`, you can use `str_replace`, since you're not matching a pattern. And you need to put the subject string in single quotes, otherwise `\n` will be treated as the escape sequence for newline.

```
str_replace('\\', '\\\\', '\n a');
```

See [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Take another delimiter and add a backslash:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('~([\\\])~', '$1$1', '\n a');
// output: \\n a
?>
```